# How to set point (x,y) in xaml page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a struct class `Position` as like Point struct.

In C#, I set the Position like `Position Northeast = new Position(13.084306, 80.210024);`

```
public struct Position 
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public Position(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to set this in XAML like `<maps:GeoBounds Northeast="9,9">`

I want the implicit conversion within the Position struct.

Anyone please suggest the solution how to I convert the Position points as like .Net struct Point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAML element syntax should work:

```
<maps:GeoBounds>
    <maps:GeoBounds.Northeast>
        <maps:Position Latitude="9" Longitude="9"/>
    </maps:GeoBounds.Northeast>
</maps:GeoBounds>
```

---

You may also write a TypeConverter that converts from `string` to `Position`:

```
public class PositionConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return Position.Parse((string)value);
    }
}
```

Register it with the Position type like this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof(PositionConverter))]
public struct Position 
{
    ...

    public static Position Parse(string positionString)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now attribute syntax like

```
<maps:GeoBounds Northeast="9,9">
```

would pass the string `"9,9"` to the Parse method, where you return an appropriate Position instance.

Comment: I checked your code. But it throws exception "Cannot assign text value '10,10' into property 'Northeast' of type ". I have edited my question and updated code above. Please check the code  and let me know what i did wrong.

Comment: Sample: https://github.com/bharathirajauk/MySamples/blob/master/GeoZoomCal_UWP.zip

Comment: And you seriously removed the upvote and accept in order to force me? Good luck!

Comment: Sorry. Initially i have accepted the answer without testing and believed that the solution will work. But after try, it was not working. If Answer is Accept state and some one tried in future, it gives wrong answer to him. So that, i revoked. Don't take it serious.

Comment: You have accpted it as the answer to your *original* question, where the solution was to use element syntax. The TypeConverter was just an alternative approach. Then you edited the question and thus totally changed its meaning. I'd strongly recommend to revert to your original question. Besides that, the TypeConverter approach just works. No idea where you went wrong.

Comment: XAML syntax was not working as Position is Struct type. So that, i tried second approach TypeConverter.

Comment: That makes no sense. XAML element syntax didn't work because you later made the Latitude and Longitude properties readonly. In your original post they were read/write, and element syntax just worked. If you have any other problem, ask a new question.

Comment: I think, there are some confusion happen by editing the actual query. I will create new query. Thanks @Clemens